# Can't send SOAP Request with Automatic made WSDL Proxy Class

Tags: visual-studio-2010, soap, wsdl

I want to retrieve the status of a order from a government web service.

The documentation file is http://www.sii.cl/factura_electronica/factura_mercado/estado_envio.pdf and the WSDL according to the doc is https://maullin.sii.cl/DTEWS/QueryEstUp.jws?WSDL.

Which for this I have tried with two ways:

1. Adding the reference directly as service reference in vs2010
2. Making a class file from wsdl.exe and then import

If I get this right, I have to send four variables.

RutCompania, DvCompania, TrackId,Token

and I did, this is my code

```
QueryEstUpServicePalena.QueryEstUpClient ClienteP= new QueryEstUpServicePalena.QueryEstUpClient();
        var xmlData = ClienteP.getEstUp(RutCompania, DvCompania, TrackId, Token);

        XmlDocument _doc = new XmlDocument();
        _doc.LoadXml(xmlData);
```

but no matter what or how, I only get a crash saying it can't connect to the server. xmlData is always null, as if I don't even get a reply from the server.

This is part of the automatic code made by wsdl.exe (full class code here http://puu.sh/fMPY3/2d9118b053.cs, notice how the RequestNamespace="http://DefaultNamespace", I replaced with the server wsdl full url and still fails).

```
public string getEstUp(string RutCompania, string DvCompania, string TrackId, string Token) {
    object[] results = this.Invoke("getEstUp", new object[] {
                RutCompania,
                DvCompania,
                TrackId,
                Token});
```

The service provider support center is awful and they don't give me any reply or help more than "Read the documentation file again"

I really don't know what to do, as I did this with another WSDL file and worked just fine.

Edit: I noticed the proxy class that works uses         System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute
the one i am trying to do now uses      System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute
http://puu.sh/fMRuZ/40bbd9fbda.png
both used wsdl.exe, I don't know why it's different

Edit 2: tried to remake the class file but still no results

```
Wsdl.exe /out:Proxy.cs /protocol:SOAP https://palena.sii.cl/DTEWS/QueryEstUp.jws?WSDL
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally i found what was the problem

I have submitted a complain to the dev team beacuse it was their fault in the end:

My research to solve it is taking the WSDL : https://maullin.sii.cl/DTEWS/QueryEstUp.jws?WSDL

1. Replace: "http://DefaultNamespace" with "https://maullin.sii.cl/DTEWS/QueryEstUp.jws"
2. Replace: "use="encoded"" with "use="literal""
3. Replace:     "http://nogal.sii.cl:3200/WSAUT/services/CrSeed" with "https://maullin.sii.cl/DTEWS/QueryEstUp.jws"

result: http://puu.sh/fMZkl/fcd33c1ea7.png  (Not giving connection errors anymore)
And that's it, solved and working, In the end i don't know if it's fault of the  jws or the default procedure of wsdl.exe, but i solved it finally

Sorry if somebody was trying to make it work already

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I added the service reference in vs2022 this link:
[image: connected service vs]

I have not modified the class generated with the tool, there are some SII services that have an error in "OperationFormatStyle.Rpc" & "OperationFormatUse.Encoded" but not this one.

This is the call:

```
var service = new ServiceEstadoUpload.QueryEstUpClient();
service.getEstUp("78055768", "9", TrackId, Token);
```

The result:
[image]